# How to recover from akka.stream.io.Framing$FramingException

Tags: scala-2.11, akka-stream

On: akka-stream-experimental_2.11 1.0.

We are using Framing.delimiter in a Tcp server. When a message arrives with length greater than maximumFrameLength the FramingException is thrown and we could capture it from OnError of the ActorSubscriber.

Server Code:

```
def bind(address: String, port: Int, target: ActorRef, maxInFlight: Int, maxFrameLength: Int)
    (implicit system: ActorSystem, actorMaterializer: ActorMaterializer): Future[ServerBinding] = {
    val sink = Sink.foreach {
      conn: Tcp.IncomingConnection =>
        val targetSubscriber = ActorSubscriber[Message](system.actorOf(Props(new TargetSubscriber(target, maxInFlight))))

        val targetSink = Flow[ByteString]
          .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = maxFrameLength, allowTruncation = true))
          .map(raw ⇒ Message(raw))
          .to(Sink(targetSubscriber))

        conn.flow.to(targetSink).runWith(Source(Promise().future))
    }
    val connections = Tcp().bind(address, port)
    connections.to(sink).run()
  }
```

Subscriber code:

```
class TargetSubscriber(target: ActorRef, maxInFlight: Int) extends ActorSubscriber with ActorLogging {
  private var inFlight = 0

  override protected def requestStrategy = new MaxInFlightRequestStrategy(maxInFlight) {
    override def inFlightInternally = inFlight
  }

  override def receive = {
    case OnNext(msg: Message) ⇒
      target ! msg
      inFlight += 1
    case OnError(t) ⇒
      inFlight -= 1
      log.error(t, "Subscriber encountered error")
    case TargetAck(_) ⇒
      inFlight -= 1
  }
}
```

Problem:
Messages that are under the max frame length do not flow after this exception for that incoming connection. killing the client and re running it works fine.

ActorSubscriber does not honor [supervision](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-error.html)

What is the correct way to skip the bad message and continue with the next good message ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put supervision on the `targetFlow` sink instead of the whole materialiser? I don't see it anywhere here and I believe it should be set on that flow directly.

Stil this is more a guess than **science** ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exception reading from a file, and for me it was solved by putting a return after last line.